# Find un-matched values from almost 2 identical table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, where I need to find un-matching values. Both the tables doesn't have any unique or primary key column.
I need to identify which row is untached along with columns which are not matching.
for example below is the visual representation of the requirement -
[image]
[image]
[image]

I tired few ways, one of the example mentioned below but its not an accurate solution.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Table2') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Table2
END
GO
CREATE TABLE #Table2
(
     Column1 int,
     Column2 varchar(50), 
     Column3 varchar(50),
     Column4 varchar(50)
)
Insert into #Table2 (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) values (1, 'CC1-1', 'GL1-1', 'ON1-1')
Insert into #Table2 (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) values (1, 'CC1-1', 'GL1-1', 'ON1-4')
Insert into #Table2 (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) values (1, 'CC1-2', 'GL1-2', 'ON1-2')
Insert into #Table2 (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) values (1, 'CC1-6', 'GL1-6', 'ON1-6')
Insert into #Table2 (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) values (2, 'CC1-6', 'GL1-6', NULL)  
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Table1') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Table1
END
GO
CREATE TABLE #Table1
(
     Column1 int,
     Column2 varchar(50), 
     Column3 varchar(50),
     Column4 varchar(50)
)
Insert into #Table1 (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) values (1, 'CC1-1', 'GL1-1', 'ON1-1')
Insert into #Table1 (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) values (1, 'CC1-1', 'GL1-1', 'ON1-4')
Insert into #Table1 (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) values (1, 'CC1-2', 'GL1-2', 'ON1-2')
Insert into #Table1 (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) values (1, 'CC1-6', 'GL1-6', 'ON1-6')
Insert into #Table2 (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) values (2, 'CC1-2', 'GL1-2', null) 

select * from #Table2
select * from #Table1
select Stg.*, Inv.*,
    case when isnull(Stg.Column2, '') = isnull(Inv.Column2, '') 
        and isnull(Stg.Column3, '') = isnull(Inv.Column3, '') 
        and isnull(Stg.Column4, '') = isnull(Inv.Column4, '') then 'Matched'
    else 'Not matching: ' +
        case when isnull(Stg.Column2, '') <> isnull(Inv.Column2, '') then 'Column2,' else '' end +
        case when isnull(Stg.Column3, '') <> isnull(Inv.Column3, '') then 'Column3,' else '' end + 
        case when isnull(Stg.Column4, '') <> isnull(Inv.Column4, '') then 'Column4' else '' end
    end as 'Remarks'
from #Table1 Stg
left join #Table2 Inv on Stg.Column1 = Inv.Column1 
    and (isnull(Stg.Column2, '') = isnull(Inv.Column2, '')
    or isnull(Stg.Column3, '') = isnull(Inv.Column3, '')
    or isnull(Stg.Column4, '') = isnull(Inv.Column4, ''))
```

Please advise a better way of doing it, I also tried left/right/outer joins with null checks but the tables can also have null values in one of the columns then its failing again.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the expected output ?

Comment: Hi @SelVazi, I thought query was sufficient enough, however I have added the images for better understanding.

Comment: Give an example of data when a query returns an incorrect result.

Comment: So you see in the output Table-> Column1 - with data 1 is all have matching data but its still giving Unmatched result which is incorrect.  hope I explained clearly.

Comment: What if 1 row from Table1 matches to 2 rows in Table2? Or vice versa?

Comment: @ValNik , If all columns of a row from table1 matches with table 2 its show Matched as a result. refer the image please.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `LEFT JOIN` as follows :

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN t1.Column2 = t2.Column2
                 AND t1.Column3 = t2.Column3
                 AND t1.Column4 = t2.Column4 
            THEN 'Matched'
       ELSE 'Not matching: ' + 
             IIF(t1.Column2 = t2.Column2, '',  'Column2,') +
             IIF(t1.Column3 = t2.Column3, '',  'Column3,') +  
             IIF(t1.Column4 = t2.Column4, '',  'Column4,')
        END AS 'Remarks'
FROM #Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN #Table2 t2 ON t1.Column1 = t2.Column1
                     AND t1.Column2 = t2.Column2
                     AND t1.Column3 = t2.Column3
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/IQ9SmxeI)

Comment: Sadly this is incorrect , giving almost the same result as my output. which is incorrect, 2 unmatched rows of column1 with value 1 has exact same data in both the table but your query says unmatched .

Comment: Could you check my recent update

Comment: no its still the same. i have tried with left, Right, Inner joins its not working , you see in remarks - Not matching: Column4, this is incorrect.